# iOS twitter login can not use web authorization

Tags: ios, twitter

```
[[TWTRTwitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession * _Nullable session, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (session) {

    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }

}];
```

Calling this method I can not achieve the website authorized twitter

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: [TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "Error obtaining user auth token.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=-1 "" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=} and error: Could not connect to the server.

Comment: @NiravHathi Have installed twitter client will jump to twitter, did not install twitter client to get the above error. I want to use the web for login without the twitter client installed, but I do not know what to do

Comment: did you add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes into .plist file for twitter ?

Comment: @NiravHathi I have added <string> twitter </ string>
<string> twitterauth </ string>，I do not know if it is missing

Comment: @NiravHathi Merry Christmas

Comment: Merry Christmas

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation

Comment: @NiravHathi I think I did it according to the document, but it did not reach the effect I wanted. If you have time, can you share a demo for me? Thank you

Comment: will you please give me your skype

Comment: @NiravHathi I am sorry I do not skype mail can be? 18280087961@163.com This is my email

Comment: I sent you mail please check

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: @NiravHathi I have resolved, Thank you!